# Significance of calculating the LCM of $3$ numbers in ratio and dividing LCM by each of them

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, ratio

I have the following ratio of $3$ numbers

$2:3:4$ with LCM$=24$

What am I exactly doing when dividing LCM by each of the number in the ratio.

Finally, I end up with a ratio

$12:8:6$

What is the significance of this? Can someone please explain with fruits, vegetables please? I am kind of poor in Maths.

Help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: The LCM is actually $12$ because $2$ and $4$ are not coprime.

Answer (score 1):

You are computing the ratios of their reciprocals.  In your example, you have computed the ratios of $\frac{1}{2}:\frac{1}{3}:\frac{1}{4}$.  In pairs, $\frac{1}{2}:\frac{1}{3} = 3:2 = 12:8$ and $\frac{1}{2}:\frac{1}{4} = 2:1 = 12:6$.  Then, $\frac{1}{2}:\frac{1}{3}:\frac{1}{4} = 12:8:6$.